# ARR/IIS10 stops responding to client after ASP.NET throws exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, arr

We have a "standard" ARR setup with 5 servers running IIS 10.

When the client application throws an exception, that specific client session then hangs.

The only way to fix it is to wait for the it to timeout, or close the browser and login to the application again.

When the client hangs, all servers pass the health test - so it appears to be client/connection related.

- client affinity is disabled
- host affinity is disabled
- The app is ASP.NET (running on .NET 4.8), running in integrated app pool

Any help would be appreciated.

The ARR server should not stop serving pages to the client that experienced the error

Comment: Make sure your ASP.NET application is configured to log errors and exceptions. Review the application log and IIS log to determine the specific error or exception that is occurring. Error messages and stack traces can provide valuable information.